# Azure Data Factory v2 using utcnow() as a pipeline parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

For context, I currently have a Data Factory v2 pipeline with a **ForEach Activity** that calls a **Copy Activity**. The **Copy Activity** simply copies data from an FTP server to a blob storage container.

Here is the pipeline json file :

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.InputParams",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false
                            },
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "FileSystemSource",
                                    "recursive": true
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "BlobSink"
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "FtpDataset",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "FtpFileName": "@item().FtpFileName",
                                        "FtpFolderPath": "@item().FtpFolderPath"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "BlobDataset",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "BlobFileName": "@item().BlobFileName",
                                        "BlobFolderPath": "@item().BlobFolderPath"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "InputParams": {
                "type": "Array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "FtpFolderPath": "/Folder1/",
                        "FtpFileName": "@concat('File_',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd'), '.txt')",
                        "BlobFolderPath": "blobfolderpath",
                        "BlobFileName": "blobfile1"
                    },
                    {
                        "FtpFolderPath": "/Folder2/",
                        "FtpFileName": "@concat('File_',formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd'), '.txt')",
                        "BlobFolderPath": "blobfolderpath",
                        "BlobFileName": "blobfile2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

The issue I am having is that when specifying pipeline parameters, it seems I cannot use system variables and functions the same way I can when for example specifying folder paths for a blob storage dataset.
The consequence of this is that `formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')` is not being interpreted as function calls but rather the actual string with value `formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')`.

To counter this I am guessing I should be using a trigger to execute my pipeline and pass the trigger's execution time as a parameter to the pipeline like `trigger().startTime` but is this the only way? Am I simply doing something wrong in my pipeline's JSON?

Comment: Without using format you can use  `utcnow('yyyyMMdd')`

Answer (score 10):

This should work:
`File_@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd')}`

Or complex paths as well:

```
rootfolder/subfolder/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'HH')}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put a dynamic expression in the default value. You should define this expression and function either when you creating a trigger, or when you define dataset parameters in sink/source in copy activity.
So either you create dataset property FtpFileName with some default value in source dataset, and then in copy activity, you can in source category to specify that dynamic expression.

[image: example]

Another way is to define pipeline parameter, and then to add dynamic expression to that pipeline parameter when you are defining a trigger. Hope this is a clear answer to you. :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. What you say is absolutely clear and what I was indeed thinking of (specifying the expression when creating a trigger). I don't want to use the dynamic expression within the datasets since in my real use case and not just the example I gave my files are of the format FileType1_{Date}.txt or FileType2_{Date}.zip. This would mean having two parameters (FileType and Extension) passed from the pipeline to the datasets instead of just one parameter (File) which contains the type, date and extension.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest you also to go with trigger using pipeline parameters. Those default values will be replaced in runtime. Just to know. Cheers.

Comment: would love an example of how you can pass in a formula such as `split(myarray,',')[1]` and then actually execute it

Answer (score 1):

Default value of parameters cannot be expressions. They must be literal strings. 
You could use trigger to achieve this. Or you could extract the common part of your expressions and just put literal values into the foreach items.